# How to add months and years instead of numbers in lattice dot plot?

Tags: r, lattice

I am relatively new to R and I am encountering a problem whenever I try to add months and year to my dot plot. When I run my data using lattice, I do it like this:

```
require(lattice)
data_conrad = read.csv("/Users/Danniel/Desktop/conrad_made_up.csv", header = TRUE)
data_conrad
lattice::dotplot(data_conrad$Patient ~ data_conrad$Value | data_conrad$Year, 
        data=data_conrad, xlab="Time", ylab="Patient", scales= list(x = list(at = seq(from = 1, to = 12, by =1))))
```

[image: This is how my plot looks like after running the code]

However, I am trying to get the actual months instead of (1,2,3,4...12), and I'm trying to replace the `"Data_Conrad$Year"` with the actual year (2010, 2011, 2012), however I am having problems with that.

After typing `dput(data_conrad)`, the output from R is the following:

```
structure(list(Patient = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 
8L), .Label = c(" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", 
" 9", "10"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2010", 
    "2011", "2012"), class = "factor"), Value = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 1L), .Label = c(" 1", " 2", " 3", 
    " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "11", "12"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm not as familiar with `lattice`, but it might help if you provided sample data to play with. It can either be from `dput(head(data_conrad))` or build programmatically, e.g., `data.frame(Year = ..., ...)`.

Comment: Absolutely! I just edited the post using 'dput(data_conrad)', thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Defining the X-axis labels with the `labels` parameter solves your problem.

You may use the following code:

```
require(lattice)

lattice::dotplot(Patient ~ Value | Year, 
                 data = data_conrad, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Patient" , 
                 scales= list(x = list(at = seq(from = 1, to = 12, by =1),
                                       labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))))
```

Yielding the following graph:

[image]

When we take a close look at the graph, it becomes apparent that *December* is missing, and although this month may be missing in the data, you still want it to appear in the graph. The root of the problem will be in the data so let's have a look:

```
str(data_conrad)
List of 5
 $ Patient: Factor w/ 10 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Month  : Factor w/ 11 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",..: 5 4 6 8 1 3 2 2 4 10 ...
 $ Year   : Factor w/ 3 levels "2010","2011",..: 1 2 3 1 3 2 1 1 3 2 ...
 $ Value  : Factor w/ 11 levels " 1"," 2"," 3",..: 1 2 7 3 4 11 8 8 2 10 ...
```

We see that all variables are `factors`, where **Month** and **Year** should be `ordered factors`. **Month** should include all twelve months. **Value** should be an `integer`. Let's put this right:

```
data_conrad2 <- data_conrad
data_conrad2$Month <- factor(data_conrad$Month, 
                             levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                             ordered = TRUE)
data_conrad2$Month <- factor(data_conrad$Year,
                             levels = ("2010", "2011", "2012"),
                             ordered =  TRUE)
data_conrad2$Value <- as.integer(as.character(data_conrad$Value))
```

Now we execute the code again with the new dataframe *data_conrad2*:

```
lattice::dotplot(Patient ~ Value | Year, 
                 data = data_conrad2, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Patient" , 
                 scales = list(x = list(at = 1:12,
                                       labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))))
```

[image]

Adding the rotation parameter `rot` may improve the readability of the graph:

```
lattice::dotplot(Patient ~ Value | Year, 
                 data = data_conrad2, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Patient" , 
                 scales= list(x = list(at = 1:12,
                                       labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                                       rot = 45))
```

)

yielding this graph:

[image]

## Be careful however

the arguments and their position in the formula to dotplot determine what is plotted on which axis

with your call in the above examples, Patient is on the y-axis and Value is on the x-axis (the years are in separate facets). No matter how you rename the labels, and however ingenuous you name the ticks on the x-axis, this is what you get.

To make this a little clearer, the following code:

```
dotplot(Patient  ~ Value  |  Year, 
        data = data_conrad2, xlab = "Value", ylab = "Patient" , 
        scales= list(x = list(at = 1:12))
)
```

gives this plot

[image]

And perhaps we are used to see the value on the Y-axis :

```
dotplot(Value  ~ Patient  |  Year, 
        data = data_conrad2, xlab = "Patient", ylab = "Value" , 
        scales= list(x = list(at = 1:12))
)
```

gives this plot

[image]

I hope this has clarified things a little bit for you.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! That was very helpful! I just had to add a 'c' in this part:
data_conrad2$Month <- factor(data_conrad$Year,
                             levels = ("2010", "2011", "2012"),
                             ordered =  TRUE)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help. If you really value the answer, you have the option to "vote it up"  with the arrows, or mark it as "the right answer".